# Manage the views generated in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rails-admin

I am currently doing a project and the gems that I've used are: devise, rails admin and cancancan.. The codes below will add the CRUD and also a default views/page

**Ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)


    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, to: :crud

    if user.role == 'admin'
        can :read, [xxxx]
        can :crud, [xxxx]

        can :access, :rails_admin 
        can :dashboard  
    end

  end

end
```

Question: Where can I find the view or page? So that I can edit the view/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ability` class is where all user permissions are defined, it does not add default views. `devise` comes with default views packaged within the gem. In order to customize those views, you would have to run the following command:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This command copies all devise views to your application under `your_app/app/views/devise` folder. You should be able to customize specific views from there. Also, [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) to configure devise views for your reference.

**UPDATE**

`Rails_admin` documentation suggests that they are strongly encouraging making edits to the dashboard views via the DSL. A few examples for your reference: [#1](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List), [#2](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List-view-table-styling).

`rails_admin` views reside packaged in the gem [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/app/views/rails_admin/main). If you absolutely need to add a lot of customizations that cannot be done using DSL then add similar view structure to your app. For eg: to customize dashboard view, create `your_app/app/views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.erb` and write your own dashboard view.

Comment: Devise is only for login/signup/forgot password/resend.. I think it's not related to any admin dashboard

Comment: @Angel Do you want to customize the admin dashboard view?

Comment: @Angel refer to the update section in my answer for rails admin views.